# Debug jython scripts

Tags: java, jython

I am writing Jython scripts in files and then calling them using Java, is there a way to debug those scripts?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should be able to do that using a remote debugger (if you're using PyDev, take a look at: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html).

If you went the other way around (and launched your program with the entry point as a Jython program which called java code), you should use the java remote debugger instead (the trick is that the language which you didn't launch directly must be remote debugged).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eclipse and pydev ( http://pydev.org/ )
and use the debugger in pydev

Comment: I think OP's question was referring to debugging a Jython script once it's been invoked from within a Java program, which I'm not sure how to do, but I think that debugging the script on its own from Eclipse/PyDev is probably the best option. If the Jython script is taking parameters from the Java program, then perhaps halt the Java program whenever it's about to call the script, observe the values it was about to pass, and then fire up PyDev and debug it using the observed values. So in that sense, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can log to stdout and/or stderr and the collect that on the java side and logging it out again.